# gsed replacement command when reading from another file that contains newlines

Tags: sed

This is a bit of a strange one. I am using gsed to edit a cloud config file before it is pushed to a server. For some reason gsed (gnu-sed) is throwing an error when I attempt to print the file into the substitution string. Various methods of escaping do not seem to work, which is rather frustrating. Can anyone see what is wrong here?

1. Read certificate file into variable

   CERT=`cat ../$1/tmp/$1-cert.csr | while read i; do echo $i; done`
2. Replace in cloud config file:

   gsed -i "/write_files:/a\ - path: /home/core/$1-cert.csr\n  permissions: 0755\n  owner: core:core\n  content: |\n    `printf '%s\n' \"$CERT\"`" ../$1/tmp/cloud-config.yaml

Error:

```
gsed: -e expression #1, char 168: unknown command: `M'
```

M happens to be the first character on the second line of the cert file:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
MIICvjCCAaYCAQAweTELMAkGA1UEBhMCVUsxFzAVBgNVBAgMDkdyZWF0ZXIgTG9u
```

Comment: 1) `CERT=$(<../$1/tmp/$1-cert.csr)`; 2) ummm... that's ugly - perhaps showing a sample input and an expected output would allow someone to provide you with a simpler alternative...

Comment: "Ugly" is an opinion. I tend to agree, but then I find most bash scripting intrinsically ugly. The input and desired output are already defined in the question. If there is a simpler way of achieving the same result I would be interested in hearing it, but I am mostly curious as to what the issue is with the code above.

Comment: Perhaps I'm just blind, but I don't see sample inputs and outputs "defined in the question". Show your `cloud_config.yaml` before and after the intended modification, and perhaps the corresponding `$1-cert.csr` as well.

Comment: I think you are concentrating on the wrong things here which is most likely my fault in not simplifying the question. The YAML is irrelevant, so is the value of $1. For simplicity you could say that the surrounding YAML is "Some text"(It's actually defined in the gsed command) and $1 is "var" The real issue is in correctly escaping the embedded printf while still inserting newlines. If you cannot help with that then I thank you for your interest but perhaps move on to something else.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using awk:

```
awk '/write_files:/{print $0 RS "- path: /home/core/certs/'"$1"'-cert.csr" RS "  permissions: 0755" RS "  owner: core:core" RS "  content: |"; while(getline line<"../'"$1"'/tmp/'"$1"'-cert.csr"){print "    "line};next}1' ../$1/tmp/cloud-config.yaml > swap.txt && mv swap.txt ../$1/tmp/cloud-config.yaml
```